# How to getting started with AppScale?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, appscale

The Appscale VM is running and I can deploy the sample guestbook app. Trying to deploy a simple GAE based hello-world-servlet works but gives me a 403 as soon as I try to access it. Since I just started with Appscale and GAE I have ho idea how to solve this error. Is there a simple hello-world sample app for Appscale ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [a collection](https://github.com/AppScale/sample-apps) of sample applications that will work on AppScale. Google's [Hello World sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/helloworld) will also work just fine after compilation.

It is unusual to get a 403 while deploying the application. Have you tried running that same application with Google's SDK? Are you deploying the app via the AppScale dashboard web page, or are you using the CLI tools?

Comment: I'm deploying with the CLI. I'm not getting the 403 when I deploy but when I try to access the deployed application.

Comment: I corrected the question to make it clear that I do not get the 403 when I deploy the app.

Comment: I would recommend checking your application's log file to see if it has any additional information about the error. It's located at /var/log/appscale/app___your-app-id.log on the VM.

Comment: Checked it, but there is no additional info. BTW: I get the following warning when deploying: AppScale did not find the correct SDK jar versions in your app. The current supported SDK version is 1.8.4.

Comment: The Java AppServer is based on the 1.8.4 SDK, so the error should disappear if you compile the app using that version. For convenience, you can download it at http://s3.amazonaws.com/appscale-build/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4.zip. However, I doubt that is responsible for the 403 you are seeing. Have you tried running the application with Google's SDK to confirm that it works? I would recommend checking your web.xml file to ensure there are no security constraints on any of the URLs. I can also take a look at the application if you'd like to email it to chris.donati@appscale.com.

Comment: I'm using the example from https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/hello-world (the servlet example). I just added an app engine-web.xml then after  runing mvn jetty:run-exploded I deployed the exploded dir.

Comment: The page you linked to is for the new flexible environment (previously known as Managed VMs), which unfortunately is not yet supported by AppScale. The equivalent page for the standard environment is here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/quickstart.